# Next.js 13 - new fetch approach makes two HTTP requests instead of one

Tags: next.js13

I'm figuring out how data fetching works in Next.js 13 and I noticed that this code, when revalidating a fetching current data, makes two HTTP requests to the server instead of one. The requests go right after each other.

```
async function getData() {
    const url = `${process.env.API_URL}/public/monitoring/websocket/`
    const res = await fetch(url, {next: {revalidate: 10}})
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }
    return res.text()
}

export default async function Home() {
    const data = await getData()
    return (<div>{data}</div>)
}
```

Q: Is there any reason why there are two HTTP requests to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for duplicate component rendering is the `React.StrictMode` setting in `development` mode.

https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development